# The mysterious card in the middle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

The referee tells Lefty, Righty, and Middly: *"I have picked three positive integers $L,M,R$ with $L<M<R$ and $L+M+R=13$, and I have written these numbers onto the three cards lying face down on the table. The left card carries value $L$, the middle card carries value $M$, and the right card carries value $R$."*

- Lefty picks up the left card, looks at it and ponders a while about it.
  Then he announces to the others: *"I am not able to determine the numbers $M$ and $R$."*
- Then Righty picks up the right card, studies the value $R$ and thinks deeply about it. Then Righty announces: *"I am not able to deduce the numbers $L$ and $M$."*
- Finally Middly takes the card in the middle and thinks about the value $M$.
  After some time he says: *"I am not able to deduce the numbers $L$ and $R$."*

> **Question:** What is the value of $M$? And what can be said about the values of $L$ and $R$?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> M is 4
>  L and R can be 1 and 8 or 2 and 7

And here's the solution:

Lefty's turn:

> L can only be 1, 2 or 3. If L were 4 or more, then M would have to be at least 5 and R at least 6, which sums up to 15, so L is at most 3.
>  If L were 3, then M and R would be 4 and 6 respectively and then Lefty would be able to guess the value. So L is 1 or 2.
>  If L were 2, then M+R would be 11, leaving 3/8, 4/7 and 5/6 as possible M/R values.
>  If L were 1, then M+R would be 12, leaving 2/10, 3/9, 4/8, 5/7 as possible M/R values.

---

Now let's go to Righty:

> If R were 11 or more, then L and M would have to be 0 or negative, so R is at most 10.
>  If R is 10, then L+M must be 3, which only leaves 1 and 2 as possible values, but Righty couldn't deduce it, so R is 9 or less. Also, as a perfect logician, Righty would know that L is 1 or 2, because if it were 3, then Lefty would know the answer.
>  If R is 9, then L+M must be 4, leaving only 1 and 3 as possible values for L and M. So R must be 8 or lower.
>  If R is 8, then L+M = 5, with possible values of: 1/4, 2/3
>  If R is 7, then L+M = 6, possible values: 1/5, 2/4
>  If R is 6, then L+M = 7, possible values: 2/5
>  If R is 5, then L+M = 8, no possible values
>  So L is [1,2] and R is [7,8]

---

Do the same for Middly:

> As a perfect logician he would know than L is 1 or 2 and R is 7 or 8.
>  So M must be between 2 and 7, L can only be 1 or 2 and R can only be 7 or 8:
>  If M is 2, then L+R = 11, possible values: none
>  If M is 3, then L+R = 10, possible values: 2/8
>  If M is 4, then L+R = 9, possible values: 1/8, 2/7
>  If M is 5, then L+R = 8, possible values: 1/7
>  If M is 6, then L+R = 7, possible values: none
>  If M is 7, then L+R = 6, possible values: none
>  From here we can deduce that M is not 3 or 5. And because Middly could not deduce it, we can see that M must be 4

---

Possible solutions:

> L    M    R
>     1    4    8
>     2    4    7

Answer (score 7):

I agree with [Novarg's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9352/novarg) [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/24258/9352), but it's a bit hard to follow. Here's how I solved it:
We can know the possible values are these:

> 1 2 10 
>  1 3 9 
>  1 4 8 
>  1 5 7 
>  2 3 8 
>  2 4 7 
>  2 5 6 
>  3 4 6

When lefty comes in

> If it was a 3, there would be no other options and he would be able to figure it out, but he didn't. 
>  1 2 10 
>  1 3 9 
>  1 4 8 
>  1 5 7 
>  2 3 8 
>  2 4 7 
>  2 5 6 
>  <strike>3 4 6</strike>

When righty goes in, he knows that lefty couldn't figure it out.

> And since he couldnt either, all unique values for R must be eliminated
>  including 6, since he would have figured out given that he knew the other 6 was eliminated! 
>  <strike>1 2 10</strike>  
>  <strike>1 3 9</strike>  
>  1 4 8 
>  1 5 7 
>  2 3 8 
>  2 4 7 
>  <strike>2 5 6</strike>  
>  <strike>3 4 6</strike>

When M comes in, the same applies for all remaining unique values for M

> <strike>1 2 10</strike>  
>  <strike>1 3 9</strike>  
>  1 4 8 
>  <strike>1 5 7</strike>  
>  <strike>2 3 8</strike>  
>  2 4 7 
>  <strike>2 5 6</strike>  
>  <strike>3 4 6</strike>

Comment: Great answer! I solved it exactly as you did! Interestingly, if the turns of L, M and R would be different, we would always get more possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Wrote the following python script to help solve this puzzle:

```
cards = set()

for l in range(1, 13):
    for m in range(l + 1, 13):
        r = 13 - m - l
        if r > m:
            hand = frozenset((l, m, r))
            if len(hand) == 3:
                cards.add(hand)

cards = sorted(tuple(sorted(list(hand))) for hand in cards)

print('L M R ')
for hand in cards:
    print '%d %d %d' % hand
```

prints out:

> L M R  
>  1 2 10 
>  1 3 9 
>  1 4 8 
>  1 5 7 
>  2 3 8 
>  2 4 7 
>  2 5 6 
>  3 4 6

So you can easily see Lefty must have seen a

> 1 or 2

And then Right had to have seen a

> 8 or 7

And therefore Middly must have seen a

> 4

And so the only solutions could be

> 1 4 8 
>  2 4 7

Comment: I can't help but think that writing that program must have taken longer than it would have taken to just write them out by hand. :)